# Replace multiple IDs in 1 field in google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I've got a website where the url contain ID's instead of names. I want to make a field in google data studio where I replace the ID with a name.

So I'm making a calculated field with a REPLACE

```
REPLACE(Page,'/courses/29124','/courses/1_8P Presenteren')
```

This is working fine, but I've got multiple unique IDs so I try to make a list of all IDs with corresponding string, like a translation table

```
REPLACE(Page,'/courses/29124','/courses/1_8P Presenteren')
REPLACE(Page,'/courses/31942','/courses/Cop1')
etc
```

But this returns an 'invalid formula' in data studio.[image]

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) would consist of just a single line, with one `Page` field and multiple `REPLACE` functions; also adding 3 other possible methods:

**1) [`REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583533):**

```sql
REPLACE(REPLACE(Page, '/courses/29124', '/courses/1_8P Presenteren'), '/courses/31942', '/courses/Cop1')
```

**2. [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058):**

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Page, '29124', '1_8P Presenteren'), '31942', 'Cop1')
```

**3. [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724):**
***NOTE***: CASE Statements are currently [Limited to 200 When Clauses](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/49446493?msgid=49452859)

```sql
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page, '/courses/29124') THEN '/courses/1_8P Presenteren'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page, '/courses/31942') THEN '/courses/Cop1'
  ELSE "Other Page"
END
```

A Visual to demonstrate:
[image]

### 4) [Data Blending](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420)

Based on the information in the comments, the following should do the trick:

**4.1) Data Source 1 - Google Analytics**

Create a field `Page_JoinKey` at the Data Source:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, "^(/[^/]*/[^/]*)")
```

Creating a Table of Data Source 1 would look like:

```
+--------------------------------+----------------+
|              Page              |  Page_JoinKey  |
+--------------------------------+----------------+
| /courses/29124/homepage        | /courses/29124 |
| /courses/29124/anotherpage     | /courses/29124 |
| /courses/29124/contacts        | /courses/29124 |
| /courses/29124/sales           | /courses/29124 |
| /courses/31942/location        | /courses/31942 |
| /courses/31942/aboutus/home    | /courses/31942 |
| /courses/31942/staff/employees | /courses/31942 |
+--------------------------------+----------------+
```

**4.2) Data Source 2 - Google Sheets**

Create a [Google Sheet](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295223) with 2 Fields: `Page` and `New Page`, so that a Table would look like:

```
+----------------+---------------------------+
|      Page      |         New Page          |
+----------------+---------------------------+
| /courses/29124 | /courses/1_8P Presenteren |
| /courses/31942 | /courses/Cop1             |
+----------------+---------------------------+
```

**4.3) Blended Data Source**

Data Source 1:

- Data Source: Google Analytics
- Join Key: `Page_JoinKey`
- Dimension: `Page`

Data Source 2:

- Data Source: Google Sheets
- Join Key: `Page`
- Dimension: `New Page`

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d2d01cb5-4788-4916-9673-655bf85de7fc) and an image to elaborate:

[image]